# New value of a column after updating SQL Server 

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a `SqlCommand`

```
UPDATE table SET intColumn = intColumn + 1 WHERE id = @id
```

Is there a way to get the new value of `intColumn` in the same `SqlCommand`?

Something like

```
UPDATE table 
SET intColumn = intColumn + 1 
WHERE id = @id; 
SELECT intColumn
```

with `ExecuteScalar`?

for example:

```
Dim x as int32 = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar("sql")
```

and the x is the new value of the `intColumn` ?

Comment: You can get the value in single variable in Update Statement. OUTPUT clause inserts the output in temp table and then you can fetch the data from that temp table.

Comment: thank you Mitch and Romil, but is it possible to provide a small example of the correct syntax of the command?

Comment: refer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query should be framed as below

```
    sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar("UPDATE table SET intColumn=intColumn+1 
                             OUTPUT INSERTED.intColumn
                             WHERE id=@id")
```